# mouseleave() return to before mouseenter()

Tags: jquery, html, css

is there anyway to return the elements `$("p")` to the exact color it had before the `mouseenter()` method was applied? Or do I need to know which color it was exactly before the `mouseenter()` and then apply that color with `mouseleave()`? I want it to return to the color that it had before when the `mouseleave()` is applied... Is there other way than knowing which color it had before `mouseenter()`?

Jquery code(I don't want to set it to blue, I want to set it the color it had before `mouseenter()`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css("color","yellow")
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css("color","blue")
    })
   })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the color to an empty string and it will use the value you initially set:

```
.mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css("color", "")
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2L2nfxjq/)**

Comment: Please note that this only works if you have the css set outside the element. If you have <p style="color: green"> this will get removed.

Answer (score 2):

Use classes. On mouseEnter add class `$(this).addClass("the_new_color")` and on mouseLeave just remove it. `$(this).removeClass("the_new_color")`. That css class should have `!important` to override the initial color.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is if you use .toggle(), then there you only need to put the "new" class, and instead of mousenter() and mouseleave() just use hover().

```
$( "p" ).hover(function() {

     $( this ).toggleClass("blue");

});
```

and in your css file:

```
.blue {

    color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, if you can, you really should be using jQuery's `.on(event)` method. It's more consistent, easier to read and is better 'practice'. You can also namespace events using this method.

This is how I would do it, now it's re-useable on any element or class, and can be styled differently for each.

```
function changeColorOnHover(elementClass) {
    var $element = $(elementClass);

    $element
        .on('mouseenter', function (event) {
            // store a reference to this element
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.addClass('is-hover');
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function (event) {
            // store a reference to this element
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.removeClass('is-hover');
        });
}
```

Check out the pen to see it in action.

http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/LNdBKY

Answer (score 0):

Just save the initial color in a variable and set it on mouse leave.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var InitialColor = $("p").css("color")
   $("p").mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).css("color", "yellow")
   })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css("color", InitialColor)
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/owzm64wa/